# For all $x \in V$ (vector space) there exists $f \in V^*$ s.t. $f(x) \neq 0$

Tags: vector-spaces, dual-spaces

I'm trying to prove that the following statement is wrong:

Let $V$ be a vector space. For all $x \in V$ there exists $f \in V^* s.t. f(x) \neq 0$

Counterexample:

Since $V$ is a vector space: $0 \in V$. And $f \in V^*$ is a linear application, since $V^*$ is the dual space. And we know that for every linear application $f(0)=0$. So the statement is wrong.

Am I right in my conclusion?

Comment: Yes, you're correct.

Comment: The correct statement is " For all non-zero x∈V there exists f∈V∗s.t.f(x)≠0."